# What is the best solution to running a PHP script in the background: Gearman or via the shell?

Tags: php, kohana-3, gearman

I want to be able to have a PHP script working in the background. So I did some research and I found two solutions:

1. Via the shell.
2. http://gearman.org/

I am wondering which solution is the best.

Also, I have seen that in PHP.ini there is a memory limitation. I am wondering how this limitation will affect my "background" PHP script, and if I need more memory which solution is the best.

**More details:**

The script that will be working in the background will encrypt a file with the help of PHP and Kohana framework.

I am using Ubuntu 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, it depends on whether you need Gearman's features or not. It's doubtful there is some magic in Gearman that would make your actual script work *better*, so unless you need *to do work in parallel, to load balance processing, and to call functions between languages*, a simple shell_exec('... &') (or a cron job) is simply less work.

Comment: Will the memory limitation in PHP affect my script if I use the shell? Would Gearman help?

Comment: Depends. Why not increase it in php.ini or with ini_set? Note that many systems use a separate php.ini for the CLI version.

Comment: True, I forgot about that. Thanks.